# What is wrong with this tweak?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cydia, tweak

I tried to compile a tweak using theos, an amazing framework to create tweaks easily on many different platform. Here I am trying to show a settings icon every time I respring and slowly fade it out but it is failing to compile. I have all the needed headers and frameworks and am running a real Mac (Despite the name u see on my terminal :P) with the latest Xcode installed and a previous install of the Xcode 4.2. This is the tweak.xm:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit2.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import <SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <substrate2.h>
#import <IOSurface/IOSurface.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore2.h>
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
#import <CaptainHook/CaptainHook.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
#import <Celestial/Celestial.h>
#import <SpringBoardServices/SpringBoardServices.h>
#import <CoreFoundation/CFNotificationCenter.h>
#import <ChatKit/ChatKit.h>

%hook CKConversationListController

- (void)composeButtonClicked:(id)clicked {
}
%end

%hook SpringBoard
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(id)application {
NSArray *animationArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"/Applications/Preferences.app/BlobIcon@2x.png"], nil];


         [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.75 target:self selector:@selector(crossfade) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    mainImageView.animationImages = animationArray;


    mainImageView.animationDuration = 4.5; //mainImageView is instance of UIImageView

    mainImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;

    [mainImageView startAnimating];


    CABasicAnimation *crossFade = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
    crossFade.autoreverses = YES;
    crossFade.repeatCount = 1;
    crossFade.duration = 1.0;
}

%new
- (void) crossfade {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut]; // user dependent transition acn be set here
    mainImageView.alpha = !mainImageView.alpha;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
%end
```

And the makefile looks like this:

```
include theos/makefiles/common.mk
export GO_EASY_ON_ME=1

TWEAK_NAME = Goofy
Goofy_FILES = Tweak.xm
Goofy_FRAMEWORKS = Foundation UIKit CoreGraphics ChatKit
Goofy_PRIVATE_FRAMEWORKS = ChatKit VoiceServices AppSupport

include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/tweak.mk
```

I am keeping on getting

```
Making all for tweak Goofy...
 Preprocessing Tweak.xm...
 Compiling Tweak.xm...
Tweak.xm: In function ‘void _logos_method$_ungrouped$SpringBoard$applicationDidFinishLaunching$(SpringBoard*, objc_selector*, objc_object*)’:
Tweak.xm:32: error: ‘mainImageView’ was not declared in this scope
Tweak.xm: In function ‘void _logos_method$_ungrouped$SpringBoard$crossfade(SpringBoard*, objc_selector*)’:
Tweak.xm:53: error: ‘mainImageView’ was not declared in this scope
make[2]: *** [.theos/obj/Tweak.xm.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [Goofy.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
Hackint0sh-HD:Goofy iHackerMe$
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't know this tool, but judging from the error message, it looks like `mainImageView` is not defined (and I don't see where you've defined it in your code snippet).

Comment: So how should i define it @Rob?

Comment: It looks like it should be a `UIImageView`. Thing is, though, that standard programs don't generally do that sort of stuff in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` (which generally only has housekeeping sort of stuff, such as maybe initializing the `window` and `viewController`, setting the `window`'s `rootViewController`, etc.), but rather in a view controller's `viewDidLoad`. But you don't even reference a view controller, so I don't know if that you're missing something fundamental, or whether the Theos framework is supposed to take care of this sort of stuff for you. I just don't know Theos.

Comment: Judging from a superficial google of Theos, it looks like doing it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is the "Theos way". So you might just need to include a line at the start of your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` that says `UIImageView *mainImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( /* set your frame coordinates in here */)];` or something like that. Hopefully a Theos experienced person will chime in here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that mainImageView hasn't been declared as anything...

Just do `UIImageView *mainImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"/Applications/Preferences.app/BlobIcon@2x.png"]];`

Unless you're trying to move an object that is already on the lockscreen like say the clock, in that case you'd need to find out what the object is, include it in the file using `#import` and then animating it like you have already.